# Multiple Loops on the same show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

I have a page that displays a users videos that he has posted and also on the same page a users videos that he has voted on.

here is my controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @videos = @user.videos.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(12)
    votes = @user.videos_with_votes("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(12)
 end
end
```

Here is my view for my show page

```
<div id="videos">
  <% @videos.each do |video| %>
    <div class="box">
  <%= image_tag video.image.url(:threeacross) %>
  <%= video.title %>
      <%= video.description %>
  <%= video.user_id %>
  <%= link_to 'Show', video %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_video_path(video) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I am confused on how to display the videos that the user has voted on in the same way that i am looping the users video posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an instance variable, e.g.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @videos = @user.videos.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(12)
   @voted_videos = @user.videos_with_votes("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(12)
 end
end

<div id="voted_videos">
  <% @voted_videos.each do |video| %>
    <div class="box">
      <%= image_tag video.image.url(:threeacross) %>
      <%= video.title %>
      <%= video.description %>
      <%= video.user_id %>
      <%= link_to 'Show', video %>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_video_path(video) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

If the display of videos and voted videos is the same than you can look to make this code:

```
    <div class="box">
      <%= image_tag video.image.url(:threeacross) %>
      <%= video.title %>
      <%= video.description %>
      <%= video.user_id %>
      <%= link_to 'Show', video %>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_video_path(video) %>
    </div>
```

a partial called `_videos.html.erb` that can be used for both `@videos` and `@voted_videos`.
Store this file (with the above code) in the same directory as the other view files

e.g.

```
<div id="voted_videos">
  <% @videos.each do |video| %>
    <% render "videos" %>
  <% end %>
</div>


<div id="voted_videos">
  <% @voted_videos.each do |video| %>
    <% render "videos" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: wow. what a great explanation. This is very useful to know and worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@votes` instead of `votes` by itself.  The `@` symbol shares the variable with the view layer so that you can do things with it (like loop over it).

Answer (score 0):

there is a concept about `instance variable` and `local variable` in rails.

whenever you define a variable with `@` symbol that particular variable is an instance variable and is accessible across its `views` and `partials`.

for eg : @videos =  @user.videos.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(12)

here `@videos` is an instance variable and persists its instance across its scope.

whereas `local` variables have its scope limited to its loop/boundry. Local variables are preferably used in loops where after the execution of the loop the variable is Garbage Collected and we can again use the same variable name for storing different value.

In your case `votes` is not accessible in your view as its a local variable, and hence to use this variable in your view you need to define this variable as instance variable (as @votes).